# Standard value for picker view

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Is it possible to set an another start point by a picker view:
Even I start my app it will show up two rows with numbers up to 60. The standard value is 00:00.

How can I make it that the start value at the first row by 60, by the second one by 45 is?

Comment: Which is it? `UIPickerView` or `UIDatePicker`? Both have methods to set the initial selected rows or value.

Comment: I use the UIPickerView...

Comment: Look at the docs for UIPickerView. There's obvious methods for selecting rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIPickerView method :

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
         animated:(BOOL)animated
```

For instance:

```
[myPickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[myPickerView selectRow:9 inComponent:1 animated:NO];
```

to select the third and the tenth values in respectively, column 1 and column 2 (without animating the change as you ask for your start values).

This init can take place in your controller's `viewWillAppear`method (if applicable).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But even I load the view, it takes a while. Why?

Comment: It is a different problem and I can't answer you without seeing your project.